# Groovy:How to update only certain tag data in xml?

Tags: xml, groovy

I  have   xml  structure  like  this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<service>
    <Income>
        <localTaxes>
            <details>
                <start>2017-09-07</start>
                <startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>
                <endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>
                <runAs>false</runAs>
                <makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
                <patch>this is  patch</patch>
                <parameter>1</parameter>
            </details>
        </localTaxes>
        <TaxyFree>
            <details>
                <start>2017-09-07</start>
                <startDate>2017-02-02</startDate>
                <endDate>2017-03-02</endDate>
                <runAs>false</runAs>
                <makeVersion>1</makeVersion>
                <patch>this is  patch</patch>
                <parameter>1</parameter>
            </details>
        </TaxyFree>
    </rs>
</Income>
```

in my  groovy  code  i  want  to   update  only   localTaxes  and  leave   other  data  unchanged ,   now    i  have   code   like  this below  but  as  a  result  i can  only  get localTaxes   updated  and  there   aren't  any  data   except   this(  i mean  i  have   only  <`service><Income><locaTaxes>...</localTaxes></Income></service>`  localTaxes  tag and   it's  relative   data  ,  **how  should   i  change  my  code  in  order  to  update  only  locaTaxes  and  make  immutable   other  part   of  xml?  :**

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(content);
            def listOfMaps = root.rs.borderCross.details.collect { node -> [
                    start: node.start.text(),
                    startDate: node.startDate.text(),
                    endDate: node.endDate.text(),
                    patch:node.patch.text(),
                    runAs:node.runAs.text(),
                    makeVersion:node.makeVersion.text(),
                    parameter:node.parameter.text()

            ]
            }  def process = { binding, element, name ->
                if( element[ name ] instanceof Collection ) {
                    element[ name ].each { n ->
                        binding."$name"( n )
                    }
                }
                else if( element[ name ] ) {
                    binding."$name"( element[ name ] )
                }
            }


            material= XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().with { builder ->
                builder.bind { binding ->
                    service{
                        rs {
                            listOfMaps.each { e ->
                                borderCross {
                                    process(binding, e, 'start')
                                    process(binding, e, 'startDate')
                                    process(binding, e, 'endDate')
                                    process(binding, e, 'runAs')
                                    process(binding, e, 'makeVersion')
                                    process(binding, e, 'parameter')
                                }


                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } )
```

Comment: What element value needs to be updated?

Comment: start  and  runAs tag   values in xml  should  be  updated